# Weight system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have started making a platform game that uses weight mechanics but I don’t know how to start coding it. For example I have a seesaw and I want it to act like real life physics which means heavy object lifts the other. Any suggestions how?

I have tried adding colliders to both sides of seesaw and made it calculate which one is heavier. But I don’t know how to use that information in order to make one lift the other (or maybe even make the other jump)

Answer (score 1):

### Players

1. Your Game object that plays on the seesaw  needs the following
   components if in 3D (rigidbody,collider)

### Note

you can assign which object is the heavier by changing the rigidbody mass [image]

**The seesaw fulcrum is optional the seesaw can work without it**

### Seesaw

The seesaw it self is made from 2 Game Objects
[image: seesaw]

1- Seesaw (The area were player can jump and play the seesaw) make sure your seesaw has a collider and a rigidbody, in the rigidody all freeze positions and the rotation on the Y and Z axis don't freeze the X axis

2- Seesaw fulcrum (The object your seesaw balances on) make sure it has only a collider and a rigidbody,  in the rigidbody freeze all its rotations and positions

make sure that the seesaw is a child game object of the seesaw fulcrum

Comment: But we did not gave any weight value how will object know if an object is heavier than the other?

Comment: In the rigidbody component in your player its called mass because mass is weight multiplied by your gravity value , the object with higher mass is the object with higher weight if the gravity value is the same

in conclusion if you want to change your gameobject weight change its mass through the rigidbody component

Comment: I added how to change weight in the answer

Comment: @DevAm00 mass multiplied by gravity is weight (just a small correction there)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works in Unity2D, but in Unity 3D you can:
Create the seesaw and position it's pivot point in the middle, then add a collider and rigidbody to it. in the Rigidbody freeze the position on all axis and the rotation on the Y and Z axis (assuming the seesaw is pivoting on the x axis).
Then, any object that will fall on the seesaw will pivot it according to it's weight (You can also tweek the properties of the seesaw rigidbody to change how the seesaw acts)

Comment: Is there a value for weight in rigidbody component

Comment: There is a value for mass, and with the physics system in Unity, it translates to weight (I don't know what g force value the engine uses, but tweak the mass value to fit your needs)

Comment: alright thanks for help and may I ask another question? What if I want to have a minimum value of weight in order to make seesaw move? For example if my weight is under 10 I will not be able to make any changes on the rotation of seesaw.

Comment: I think you can increase the mass of the seesaw but that's a solution from the top of my head and might not always suit you